# Maven dependency for LDAP library could not be resolved in OSGi

Tags: maven, ldap, osgi, aem, maven-dependency-plugin

I am trying to import

```
import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool;
import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig;
import org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.DefaultLdapConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapConnection;
import org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapConnectionConfig;
import org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapConnectionPool;
import org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.ValidatingPoolableLdapConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.directory.ldap.client.template.LdapConnectionTemplate;
```

and using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-ldap-client-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.AM4</version>
</dependency>
```

in the parent pom and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-ldap-client-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in the bundle pom.

The issue is

```
- The artifact is not present in osgi after build and
- Project bundle is in resoved state due to error 

org.apache.commons.pool2,version=[2.6,3) -- Cannot be resolved
org.apache.commons.pool2.impl,version=[2.6,3) -- Cannot be resolved
org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api,version=[2.0,3) -- Cannot be resolved
org.apache.directory.ldap.client.template,version=[2.0,3) -- Cannot be resolved
```

**UPDATED QUESTION** -

> "How to resolve these dependencies? Which ldap dependency/library
>   could be used in OSGi?"

Objective - I'm trying to connect LDAP

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapNetworkConnection( "localhost", 10389 );
```

Reference - [LDAP Connection documentation](https://directory.apache.org/api/user-guide/2.1-connection-disconnection.html)

Comment: you need to create a dependency OSGI bundle(jar) out of your dependency and upload into AEM sling console. you can find info online to convert OSGI bundle from jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to distinguish between *build time* and *runtime* dependencies. In Maven you define your *build time* dependencies. Per default they have *nothing* to do with the bundles installed in AEM (*runtime* dependencies).

To make it clear:

> Dependencies defined in Maven are *not* automatically installed into AEM.

There are a few options how you can *deploy* the required *runtime* dependencies to AEM:

1. Install them by hand (`/system/console/bundles`)
2. Put them in a content package and deploy that content package by hand.
3. Extend your Maven build to create a content-package which includes the bundles you need at runtime (e.g. `org.apache.directory.api:api-ldap-client-api:2.0.0.AM4`)
4. Install the bundles using the `install` directory of AEM on the hard disk: `crx-quickstart/install`.

All of them have advantages and disadvantages. I usually opt for option #3. I have written a lengthy answer that explains this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56698917/190823

Comment: Understood the fact that every maven dependency does not get installed in OSGi automatically.

Comment: But `org.apache.directory.api:api-ldap-client-api:2.0.0.AM4` is not active when installed manually due to unresolved dependencies. Is there any dependency that can be used in `OSGi` either `deploying it manually or with maven build`

Comment: @AbhishekSinha if you read the answer I linked I explained how you can build a bundle of the LDAP library that contains contains the missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require them, you can exclude them in the  section, by doing something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <instructions>
    <Import-Package>
      !org.apache.commons.pool2,
```

And so on.

Comment: They are required. Can't exclude them.

Comment: In that case try with: <Export-Package>

Comment: Export package is to define packages of current bundle,when added as dependency, that could be available to be used by other bundles